# How to fetch data from api and set to image slider?

Tags: react-native

I am new to reactnative and I am trying to make the imagesilder. I am trying to get data from the api and set it to the imageslider.  I have to get the **image** tag from the api and set it to the imageslider.My api is as follows:

```
[ 
 { 
   "title":"Taylor Swift",
    "artist":"Taylor Swift",
    "url":"https://www.amazon.com/Taylor-Swift/dp/B0014I4KH6",
   "image":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61McsadO1OL.jpg",
   "thumbnail_image":"https://i.imgur.com/K3KJ3w4h.jpg"
},
{ 
   "title":"Fearless",
   "artist":"Taylor Swift",
   "url":"https://www.amazon.com/Fearless-Enhanced-Taylor-Swift/dp/B001EYGOEM",
   "image":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qmhXWZBxL.jpg",
   "thumbnail_image":"https://i.imgur.com/K3KJ3w4h.jpg"
 }
 ]
```

I cant  get the image data from the api and to render it inside the render function. I have implemented as follows:

```
export default class ViewpagerP extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, images: [], data: [] }
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then((data)=>{for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                data: data[index]
            }) 
        }})    
}
render() {
    const { images } = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageSlider style={styles.viewPagerStyle}
                loopBothSides
                autoPlayWithInterval={1000}
                images={images}
                customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                    <View key={index} style={style}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.customImage} />
                    </View>

                )}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then((response => this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            data: response.data,
        }))
        )
      }
```

And in render

```
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />    
                </View>
            )
        }
        console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageSlider style={styles.viewPagerStyle}
                loopBothSides
                autoPlayWithInterval={6000}
                images={this.state.data}
                customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                    <View key={index} style={[style]}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.customImage} />
                    </View>

                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below and it will works, since you forgot to add data state in you image slider library, that's why you are not getting your desired result

```
export default class ViewpagerP extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, images: [], data: [] }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
      .then(response => response.json())

      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            data: responseJson
        })
      })

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageSlider style={styles.viewPagerStyle}
          loopBothSides
          autoPlayWithInterval={1000}
          images={this.state.data}
          customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
            <View key={index} style={style}>
              <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.customImage} />
            </View>

          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: share your snack link here so that it can be debugged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203642/discussion-between-nbn-and-abhikumar22).

Answer (score 0):

As you already have `images` in state, utilize that only.

```
.then((data)=>{
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            images:data
        }) 
    })
```

Now you have your response within `this.state.images`, so just need to do one change which is inside `customSlide`

```
customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
            <View key={index} style={style}>
                <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.customImage} />
            </View>
)}
```

`item` will give you whole single node we need to extract `image` from that element, so we will write `item.image`